# App no available error while using Play market Closed alpha testing

Tags: google-play, in-app-billing

I configured Closed Alpha Testing with one developer account and uploaded an APK.

After some hours the application has been published to market but if I use the Opt-In url with the phone with the developer account I get:

```
 App not available
 A beta  version of this app hasn't been published yet or isn't available on this account.
```

As I used the closed beta methos in teory I haven't to do anything more, have I?

Does anyone used closed beta testing and had similar problem?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you got any progress on it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not test your in app billing implementation with a device that has your publisher account signed in. You should test the application with the device that has the testing account that you might have setup in your closed Aplha testing.

Comment: Thanks, I already know it. And I used another account that it's different from my publisher account.

Comment: What if I have multiple accounts on one device?